# What sort of boat transported transport the French colonial Governors of New Orleans?

Tags: 18th-century, colonial-america, boats

I am writing a description of the changeover of the French colonial Governors of New Orleans in 1753, from Vaudreuil to Kerlérec. There is mention of a Governor's boat used to take important guests to and from Balize while the ocean going ships were delayed by the lightering necessary to cross the bar at the Passes to the Gulf. I am wondering what sort of boat this could have been and whether it might have been part galley rowed by slaves or soldiers. Most grateful for ideas on this.

Comment: I would think it very unlikely to, be a *galley*, though a rowed tender or lighter is quite possible, to avoid dependence on favourable wind. More likely, from first principles, is a *[ship's boat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship%27s_boat) as illustrated here, manned by sailors from whichever vessel supplied the transport.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I may have to use a bit of artistic licence. The actual boat sent to collect  Kerlérec and later to dispatch Vaudreiul must have been able to accommodate passengers overnight on what I imagine was a two day journey between New Orleans and the Passes..

Comment: Captain Bligh sailed his 18 loyal crew members [over 3500 nautical miles in an open *ship'slaunch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutiny_on_the_Bounty#Bligh's_open-boat_voyage) after being set adrift following the mutiny on the Bounty.

Comment: That is a good example. I have also discovered that they were building grander versions for the American waterways, and that in 1776 they had a a fleet  that included warships called gondolas and slightly bigger one called Xebecs. Both had oars and sails. This one was built in 1753 https://rcwarshipcombat.com/threads/le-requin-cebek-aos.442442/ and although it's a little bigger than the one I was imagining I think it will protect me against the accusation of anachronism.